# Discord.py channel.connect() does not work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, voice

This is the command:

```
    @commands.command(name="join", pass_context=True)
    async def join(self, ctx):
        print("1")
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        print("2")
        if not channel:
            print("3")
            await ctx.send("You're not connected to any voice channel !")
            print("4")
        else:
            print("5")
            voice = discord.utils.get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
            print("6")
            if voice and voice.is_connected():
                await voice.move_to(channel)
            else:
                print("7")
                voice = await channel.connect()
                print("8")
```

This is the main.py file:

```
import discord, os, asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = TOKEN

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents, help_command=None)


async def load():
  for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
      await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')


async def main():
  await load()
  await bot.start(TOKEN)

asyncio.run(main())
```

My bot is not connecting to any voice channel, Intents are all enabled, he got administrator and the voice channel is not private.

the output is this:
1
2
5
6
7

Answer (score 0):

try just:

```
channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
```

instead of

```
channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
```